# How does one correctly solve for the graph of $r^{2} = 36sin(2θ) $?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

What I did to solve was:

$r^{2} = 36sin(2θ)$

$r = \sqrt{36sin(2θ)}$

$r = 6 \sqrt{sin(2θ)}$

I set the $2θ = π/2$

so the incriminator is $π/4$

So by incrementing π/4:

$θ = 0, π/4, π/2, 3π/4, π/ 5π/4, 3π/2, 7π/4$

And the corresponding r’s evaluated are:

$r = 0, 6, 0, 6i, 0, 6, 0, 6$

So the pairs are:
$0,0$

$π/4, 6$

$π/2, 0$

$3π/4, 6i$

$π, 0$

$5π/4, 6$

$3π/2, 0$

$7π/4, 6$

When I graph these I get a rose. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Please show your graph.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I can it's on paper. Are the points correct?

Comment: Take a photo of the paper with your cellphone, save the file, then upload it to this site.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork sorry it's sideways http://imgur.com/a/hO87j

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with your result. Notice that for $\theta \in (\frac{\pi}2, \pi)$ our $r^2$ goes negative, so we don't have a defined $r$.  $r$ then begins to be defined when we have  $\theta \in (\pi, \frac{3\pi}2)$ again. I believe that you have drawn a dotted line for these - a dotted line is used normally to indicate $r$ has gone negative but is still defined. - $r$ has to be real!! ignoring where you have these dotted lines is exactly the discrepancy between the David plotted and your answer.

Comment: Sorry just noticed that you haven't used dotted lines so ignore that. But the point remains that for top left and bottom right quadrants we get an undefined $r$ -and this is where the discrepancy between your graph and the true graph lies.

Comment: @SEWillB so whenever I have negative radius should I consider that positive instead or just ignore it altogether? Also got an 'i' wasn't sure how o graph it that. So when 'i' or a negative radius pops up I just don't consider it and move on to the next one in line?

Comment: No sorry, I should have explained that better. Negative radius is perfectly fine and should be plotted- it means that you go the opposite side of the origin to the angle we're at. For example, if at $\theta=\frac{\pi}2$, we have $r=-1$ we plot this as the point $-i$ on the Argand diagram, rather than the point $i$ which has the argument $\frac{pi}2$ and positive $r=1$. It is the imaginary $r$'s with the $i$'s that you get that should be completely ignored. As I tried to explain, these imaginary $r$'s will appear in the top left and bottom right quadrants, and ignoring will give you the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple plot of the function:

[image]

Comment: It is a famous curve : a Bernoulli's lemniscate.